# inline matplotlib pyplot saturated while scipy.misc toimage is not

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am reading a ddsm mammogram image. And after normalizing plotting it. THis is Grayscale image but I am treating it as RGB, by copying the same channel 3 times. The problem is when I use `pyplot` from `matplotlib` the normalized image gets saturated whereas when I plot using `scipy.misc` `toimage`, it doesn't

Here is my code:

```
from scipy import misc
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = misc.imread('testcolor.png') 
print(type(img) ) #<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
img.shape #(512,512,3)
```

The image pixel values are like this

```
print(img[:,:,1])
#[[ 98  97  99 ...,   0   0   0]
 [ 98  98 100 ...,   0   0   0]
 [100 100 100 ...,   0   0   0]
 ..., 
 [ 91  95  96 ...,   0   0   0]
 [ 88  89  92 ...,   0   0   0]
 [ 95  94  97 ...,   0   0   0]]
```

Then I normalized the image with the following code:

```
imgn = np.where(img>0,img,np.nan)
img_norm = (img - np.nanmean(imgn,axis=(0,1)))/np.nanstd(imgn,axis=(0,1))
```

As before normalized pixels are like

```
print(img_norm[:,:,1])
#[[-0.71566175 -0.74025369 -0.69106981 ..., -3.1256717  -3.1256717
  -3.1256717 ]....
```

Also

```
print(np.min(img_norm)) #-3.12567170176
print(np.max(img_norm))#2.80098542174
```

With matplotlib pyplot I get this:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img_norm)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with matplotlib]

Then I plot the same normalized image with `toimage` from `scipy.misc`

```
from scipy.misc import toimage
toimage(img_norm).show()
```

[image]

Why I am having this discrepancy?

Btw, the unormalized original image is this:

[image]

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `uint8` to show image? Also, what about negative numbers in `img_norm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it helps to read [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

> `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(X, .... )`
>
> `X` : array_like, shape (n, m) or (n, m, 3) or (n, m, 4)
>
> Display the image in X to current axes. X may be an array or a PIL image. If X is an array, it can have the following shapes and types:
>
> MxN – values to be mapped (float or int)
> MxNx3 – RGB (float or uint8)
> MxNx4 – RGBA (float or uint8)
> **The value for each component of MxNx3 and MxNx4 float arrays should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0.** MxN arrays are mapped to colors based on the norm (mapping scalar to scalar) and the cmap (mapping the normed scalar to a color).

Your array is a float array, but not in the range between 0 and 1. Hence the behaviour of `imshow` is undefined.

You may normalize to the range between 0 and 1 using normal math operations or, potentially more easily using `plt.Normalize`, in case you want a linear mapping.

```
norm = plt.Normalize(0,1)
plt.imshow(norm(img_norm))
```